# But how can I check and wait with PowerShell if provisioning of the SiteCollection is complete

Tags: powershell, office-365

I have used CSOM and PowerShell to create a SiteCollection  in o365.

```
$tenant.CreateSite($properties) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

But how can I check and wait if provisioning of the SiteCollection is complete?

Thanks for your help
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the followin in PowerShell:

```
#retrieve the SPO Operation return value during creation
$spOnlineOperation = $tenant.CreateSite($properties)

#load the tenant object
$ctx.Load($tenant)
#load the SPO operation
$ctx.Load($spOnlineOperation)
#run the command
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#wait for SPO Operation to complete
while($spOnlineOperation.IsComplete -eq $false)
{
  write-host “Waiting…” -ForegroundColor Yellow
  Start-Sleep 10
  $spOnlineOperation.RefreshLoad()
  $tenantCtx.ExecuteQuery()
}


Write-Host "Completed creation of site collection."
```

Similarly in CSOM:

```
SpoOperation spo = tenant.CreateSite(siteCreationProperties);
ctx.Load(tenant);
//We will need the IsComplete property to check if the provisioning of the Site Collection is complete.
ctx.Load(spo, i => i.IsComplete);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for site collection to be created.");
//Check if provisioning of the SiteCollection is complete.
while (!spo.IsComplete)
         {
             //Wait for 30 seconds and then try again
             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
             spo.RefreshLoad();
             ctx.ExecuteQuery();
         }
Console.WriteLine("Site collection created.");
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot instantiate a tenant object by calling the constructor with the site context. I know this is an old post but does anyone have